# App sends another session cookie when embedded in an iframe

Tags: session, cookies, iframe, content-security-policy

I'm currently developping an embedded Shopify app, which is basically an app loaded in an iframe on the Shopify admin interface. It uses a session cookie to store an access token to the Shopify API.

The problem is, **my app's backend receive a different session cookie** depending on wether the app is loaded inside the Shopify iframe or not.

The domain is the same for both cookies and `SameSite=none`.

Looks like the browser is sandboxing the cookies of the same domain if they're set from an iframe. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

It can be 3 issues:

1. Sometimes you can have a few different cookies with the same name. Browser send all of them, but on the server side commonly associative array is used (like `$_COOKIE` in PHP). Therefore last cookie overrides all previous with the same name.
   It can so happens that iframe gets not the same cookie as a main page.
   With Apache server you can access all same name cookies via `apache_request_headers()` func. RTFM for workaround for other servers.
2. Check the [SameSite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) attribute ob cookie - do you use `SameSite=Lax` / `SameSite=Strict` attribute or without such attribute.
    Note that `SameSite=None` requires `Secure` attribute in the modern browsers, therefore works over `https:` only.
3. The "same domain" is a wrong term, browsers operate the "same origin" term:

   "origin" is a tuple of `sheme://` + `hostname` + `port-number`.
   Therefore all 3 parts should match, not domain name only.